# Fetch console showing value but cant save it to a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

This is what I have .

```
var a;

handleSubmit(event) {
  var a ;
  event.preventDefault();
this.setState({username:'poop'})
console.log("submit");
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/login/'+this.state.username+'/'+this.state.password,{
    method: 'GET',
    

  }).then((resp)=> resp.text())
  .then(resp => {
console.log(resp) 
a = resp;

 });

console.log(a);
```

My issue is that the `console.log(resp)` will log the correct value I need ("Success") but when I try to do `var a = resp` it shows up as undefined. my API returns one string, either success or fail. The log will show success but for some reason I can not get it assigned to a variable.

Comment: That code is incomplete. Where do you assign "a" and where you check the value that is undefined?

Comment: @AlanGrosz just fixed it for more clarity

Comment: Ok. @Shubham Khatri has answered. The problem is the asynchronous request. If you set a console.log after the http call, it will be undefined. You must do it inside the then or using an await

Comment: @AlanGrosz what is the purpose of using await? I saw it a bunch of times just never really understood its importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous request within `handleSubmit` and hence you won't get the result immediately after fetch Request in the manner you are trying to access it, you can store the result in state using `setState` and access it elsewhere with `this.state.data`

```
handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({username:'poop'})
    console.log("submit");
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/login/'+this.state.username+'/'+this.state.password,{
        method: 'GET',
      }).then((resp)=> resp.text())
      .then(resp => {
          console.log(resp) 
          this.setState({data: resp});
      });
}
```

Alternatively you can make use of [`async-await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) like

```
async handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({username:'poop'})
    console.log("submit");
      const a = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login/'+this.state.username+'/'+this.state.password,{
        method: 'GET',
      }).then((resp)=> resp.text())
     console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: the second method worked! could you just explain to me why I have to do it like that? the first method still gave me a blank response. nothing was saved in the state for some reason.

Comment: setState is async so you wouldn't see the updated value immediately, you can use `this.setState({data: resp}, () => {console.log(this.state.data)});` to see the updated state. Also async-await is a syntax provided by javascript for promises whereby the code waits for the result before proceeding further. Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: awesome, when you say setState is not immediate, I thought it was. when we change the state of something in react the changes happen immediately on screen. for example if i have a <h>this.state.demo<h> and I do a set set state on it, i see the change immediately.

Comment: They happen immediately but take an additional render to reflect the change, you won't see the update immediately in the same function after writing `this.setState()`